# How to renew LetsEncrypt SSL wildcard?

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt, certbot

I have to renew my SSL certificate, but I want to use a wildcard certificate instead of my current simple SSL using LetsEncrypt also. I usually use this command below, but it doesn't work to update my SSL certificate as a wildcard.

```
certbot renew
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this new command below, it's going to ask to confirm which domain would you like to update and to add a DNS TXT record to validate your domain, after that restart your services and your SSL is gonna work

```
certbot certonly --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d 'mydomain.com,*.mydomain.com'
```